# What is the solution to $\lim_{x\to0^-} x^x?$

Tags: limits, chain-rule

$$\lim_{x\to0^-} x^x.$$

Symbolab says it's [1](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto0%5E%7B-%7D%7D%5Cleft(x%5E%7Bx%7D%5Cright)). My answer sheet says it does not exist. Which is correct, and can you explain the solution?

Comment: If you change that little minus sign to a plus sign then the limit indeed equals $1$. But with the minus sign as written, $x^x$ is not even well-defined in any reasonable sense for negative numbers. And so no, the limit as $x \to 0^-$ does not exist.

Comment: @LeeMosher If we permit the use of complex numbers, then

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{-x(\log(x)+i(2n+1)\pi)}=1$$

Comment: If you interpret $x^x$ as a function with domain $[(-\infty, 0) \cap \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}] \cup (0, \infty)$ where $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ is the rational numbers with odd denominator, then $\lim_{x\to 0^-} x^x$ does not exist: 0 is a cluster point from the left of $p/q$ with $p$ even and $q$ odd for which the function approaches 1, but also a cluster point from the left of $p/q$ with $p$ odd and $q$ odd for which the function approaches $-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term $$x^x$$ is only defined for all reals if $$x>0$$ holds.

Comment: The statement is true, but phrased in a confusing manner. "is only defined for all reals" should read "is only defined if," as precisely it **isn't** defined for all reals.

Comment: you must read the whole sentence

Comment: I did. And that is what my comment is about (besides the fact that "is hold" is not grammatically correct, which is a detail). (I did upvote this answer, yet I must insist the statement is semantically incorrect.)

Comment: hm and what is grammatically correct?

Comment: thank you for your grammar lesson

Comment: If we permit the use of complex numbers, then

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{-x(\log(x)+i(2n+1)\pi)}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  I see the question has changed slightly since I began typing the first draft of this.  I added clarification to answer the actual question, and left the rest of the post in its entirety in case it helps a future viewer.

---

$\lim_{x \to 0} x^x$ does not exist.

$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 1$.

Note the subtle difference.  In the limit that exists, we approach $x$ only from the right.  The limit that doesn't exist is the two-sided limit.  This is because $x^x$ is not defined for $x < 0$, therefore we cannot approach $x=0$ from the left.  Note that this also implies that $\lim_{x \to 0^-} x^x$ does not exist.

As for why the defined limit is 1:

$$x^x = e^{\ln x^x} = e^{x \ln x}$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 
  \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{x \ln x} = e^{\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\ln x}.$$

We can push the limit inside the exponent like that because limits can be pushed into and pulled out of continuous functions.

Anyway, we can use l'Hôpital to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\ln x$.

\begin{align}
  \lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln x &= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{1/x}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{x \to 0^+} (-x)\\[0.3cm]
    &= 0
\end{align}

Therefore $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = e^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that $x^x$ is ill-defined when $x < 0$, which is the domain your limit is considering. For example, $(-0.5)^{-0.5}$ is not defined. $(-1/3)^{-1/3}$ exists, but $(-1/4)^{-1/4}$ does not, and so on. In fact there are negative values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$ so that $x^x$ is not defined. By the definition of the limit, in such a case the limit cannot be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Is it considered over real domain? If so, then the limit does not exists, because $$x^x=e^{xlog(x)}$$ and one cannot take a logarithm of a non-positive number.